# jquery click function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below code is working when i paste it in the browser directly (chrome console). But it is not working from my source file

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(".test").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find("div").toggle();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks all.. It s working with document.ready :):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replace $ by writing jQuery..

like,

jQuery(function(){

Answer (score 4):

Try running it only after the DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){

  $(".test").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().find("div").toggle();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you wrap in the document.ready function. it ensure that it will bind the function when the page load completes. [Document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".test").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().find("div").toggle();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Always do this while using jquery

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $(function(){
        $(".test").on("click", function(){
        $(this).parent().find("div").toggle();
        });
     });
});
```

Always put code in the function this will make it work with and with out document ready.