# Selecting the parent of a child if it has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have been trying to change some things with the Flexslider v2 to fit my needs.
I have been trying to use jQuery to target the parent `li` of the `img class="active"` because i want to give it a class of `selected` but I have not been very successful

```
<ol class="foo">
  <li>
    <img src="bar.png" class="active">  <-- This class changes img elements depending on the active slide
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="bar.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="bar.png">
  </li>
</ol>
```

I came up with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.foo li').children().each(function(index, value) {
     if($(value).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
     } else {
         $(this).parent('li').removeClass('selected');
     }
  });
});
```

and it works in the console, but it does nothing within my main.js file.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gnmfz/ <- works for me. Surely there's something else other than the code/markup you posted?

Comment: Yes, as i wrote, i'm using the Flexslider v2 plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/akirij/4/edit)**</kbd>

Simple like one line:

```
$('.foo li').find('img.active').closest('li').addClass('selected');
```

Or if you really need it:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/akirij/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('.foo li').find('img').each(function(index, el) {
    if($(el).hasClass('active')) {
        $(el).closest('li').addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(el).closest('li').removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[jQuery API Documentation - Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**</kbd>

Comment: You copied my one. :D But a little change. That's OK.

Comment: @AspiringAqib I was able to see your answer just now after I refreshed the browser

Comment: This looks simple, but is there a way to make it run everytime the `active` class shifts to another `img` element?

Comment: @JimiD sure you can, put that line of code into a function and run your function wherever you want. Additionally you might use `$('.seleceted').removeClass('selected');` before applying to the new ones.

Comment: @roXon he said when `active` class is added to any img then also add `selected` class programmatically to its parent.

Comment: @roXon I have tried writing it like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cX3nu/) but i must be doing something wrong

Comment: I forgot to use the jQuery lib in that fiddle, and it works. But i can't get it to work in my own project. At least the script works, so now i just have to find out what is stopping mine from working. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it i document.ready like  this in your main.js and then it should work as expected.
You got it worked in console because all elements are loaded when you runt the script.

```
$(function(){
    $('.foo li').children().each(function(index, value) {
      if($(value).hasClass('active')) {
          $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
      } else {
         $(this).parent('li').removeClass('selected');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: I will just edit my question, i forgot to add that it is already within a document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use closest():

```
$(this).closest('li'),addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Where did you get a table from? ...because I need a new one for my lounge. HAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA - so funny me

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.foo li').children().each(function(index, value) {
    if($(value).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('selected');
    }
});
    });
```

Check the [similar question HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680156/jquery-click-function-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.foo > li').removeClass('selected').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('img').hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use `.each()` ? When we can achieve our goal without it.

```
$(".foo li img.active").parent().addClass("selected");
```

Comment: the problem is that the class changes between the image tags i would like the selected class to change with it

Comment: @JimiD then you need timer function. Because your code will also addClass to the img tag only one time e.g. `onload of document`

Comment: A timer would have been perfect if it wasn't because the slider can be paused when the mouse hovers on it. Then the timer would have to go off to often for it too look like it actually follows

Comment: clear the timer on mousehover and on mouseout start it again. But this stuff is not reliable.